# How to test BDD features that require a flag set in order to run?

Tags: bdd

Hi I automated some features using a BDD Framework.

When I pass a given URL, my framework should only work for certain areas not all the features due to access restrictions

There is a flag set to true if there is an access to the feature and when this flag is set the test should be run

Comment: Your question is too vague to understand. Please edit the question so that people can understand the question clearly. Also please  a suitable title for the question, as the title also is vague.

Comment: Please explain more about that flag.  What is it called? How is it normally set?  Is this just for testing or does it apply to the application itself.

Comment: Reworded and retitled

Comment: Use filters / tags for each profile.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you figure out the screen or process or parameter that will you give you access to those features.  The application is designed to control access so you need to determine how to grant that access.
Frequently this means having access to an admin account so the organization needs to allow that process to happen.  Often the bottleneck here is "but I can't put an admin username and password in my code in clear text".  That is certainly as issue - and a separate question - that can be resolved through a number of methods.
Probably the most important factor is that testing should be done using a test database with test database credentials and that instance is different from production with its own, different, admin credentials.